# Integer is String - how can that be?

Tags: java

Something terribly wrong is happening.

I have

```
ArrayList<Integer> activitiesToDelete;
```

I need to prepare array of objects to pass to Spring jdbcTemplate. However for some reason element in ArrayList is treated as String, so breaks at the point of execution of jdbcTemplate, complaining that it can't convert from String to int. Then I tried to convert within the loop to see if that would help :-\ And I obviously can't do Integer.parseInt as IDE treats it correctly as Integer. Whenever I assign Integer a = activitiesToDelete.get(i); It gives me:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Same for int a = ...
How can that be?

```
 Object [] objectList = new Object [activitiesToDelete.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < activitiesToDelete.size(); i++) {

    Integer a = activitiesToDelete.get(i);

        logger.info(String.valueOf(activitiesToDelete.get(i)));

        objectList[i] = activitiesToDelete.get(i).intValue();
}

    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, objectList);
```

What am I missing in here?

**UPDATE: Culprit line**

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/activities/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST) public String deleteActivities(@RequestParam("activityId") ArrayList <Integer> activitiesToDelete)
```

**This is a snippet related to Spring MVC where it gets populated from form, it seems that Spring can't add proper types to the ArrayList.**

Anyone wondering, either use int[] or HttpServlet methods(extra code though).

Comment: It's the other way around -- Integer is ***not*** a String. Check it out: activitiesToDelete is not the same as activitiesIdsToDelete, and it holds Strings, not Integer objects. This is nothing more than a basic error on your part, one we all do often. So no sweat -- fix it.

Comment: You're missing the code that shows how you populate the activitiesToDelete.

Comment: sorry that is typo I made in here, in code it is as it should be(thanks I'l update)

Comment: It still holds Strings. Double check where you fill it with objects. This JVM error message is rarely wrong.

Comment: How can it hold String if it is type of Integer? I populate in controller: @RequestMapping(value="/activities/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String deleteActivities(@RequestParam("activityId") ArrayList <Integer> activitiesToDelete)

Comment: There's code you're not showing us that holds the error. Trust me. Trace back and you'll find it.

Comment: @Aubergine Generics can be bypassed in certain "unsafe" operations, such as `rawArrayList = genericArrayList; rawArrayList.add(wrongType)`; the compiler should warn about these. Create a minimal self-contained test-case (this should include *how* the data is added).

Comment: Provide a few lines of the stack trace. The problem could be on a different line. Or it could be like what @pst says. The List might have been manipulated using unsafe code.

Comment: I think I did find. This happens on the line I provided in comments for the controller handler. It seems that Spring Framework adds String and cannot distinguish the type of the ArrayList. This is the first time I tried to use more complex data structure. It works with int[] perfectly. Does anyone know the way I can use data structures besides the plain array to capture form input with Spring? I can still use HttpServlet getParameter or getAttribute, but it would be better shorter to do it with spring.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us and posting your isolation of the problem and its solution. You might want to post it as an "answer" as well. 1+

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

```
objectList[i] = activitiesToDelete.get(i).intValue();
```

intValue() turns an Integer into an int. An int is not an Object, so it has to turn it into an Object to store it and I think its chosen toString. Try

```
objectList[i] = activitiesToDelete.get(i);
```

Comment: No, Java wouldn't arbitrarily change an int into a String, and besides, the error occurs before this line.

Comment: yes hovercraft is correct, please see my comment in the comments for the main post. Spring controller handler adds form input as String to ArrayList, while working normally with int []